# Regular expression and checking occurrences

Tags: c, regex

I am actually dealing with regular expressions and i am still trying to understand how to approach properly this kind of problems.

So lets say i have this regular expression:

```
[A − Z]
∗01∗
[ˆ[A − Z]]{3}
```

On alphabet [A-Z][0-9]

First question is:
{3} means that there must be atleast 3 characters that belong to a "part" of the regular expression(lets say 3[A − Z]) or it is strictly refering to the last  one ([ˆ[A − Z]])?

My second doubt is: if it is the last one, checking if there are atleast 3 occurrences might be easy(just 3 states that check if the char is a number, otherwise exit),right?
Otherwise, if it might be any of the possible part of the regular expression, how do i check without a counter(eventually confirm if i shouldnt be using a counter) how many occurrences repeat in any possible state?

I am not really interested in a solution with code, i just want to fully understand the topic.

Comment: 1) Yes 2) Use a regex library

Comment: @klutt: Huh? In the regular expression syntaxes I am familiar with, `{3}` means there must be three instances of the previous thing, not three characters that belong to part of the regular expression. And no, it would not recognize three instances of `[A-Z]` in this case; it would require three instances of `[^[A-Z]]`.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is very useful for explaining regexes.  Though note that `regex.h` uses POSIX regexes which are different from most commonly used regexes today. You'll instead want to use something like [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/).

Comment: @EricPostpischil I read to quickly. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are a formal mathematical construction, but syntaxes for describing them may vary. In common syntaxes, `{3}` means the previous item is repeated three times. For example, `[AB]{3}` is the same as `[AB][AB][AB]`, so it will match `AAA`, `AAB`, `ABA`, `ABA`, `BAA`, `BAB`, `BBA`, or `BBB`. Or `(AA|B){2}` will match `AAAA`, `AAB`, `BAA`, or `BB`. It does not require there be two characters. It requires there be two matches of `(AA|B)`.

What the “previous item” is may depend on the particular syntax you are using. For example, in `AA|B{2}`, either `|` or `{…}` could be given a higher precedence, so it could be `AA|(B{2})` or `(AA|B){2}`, depending on the rules in your syntax. However, in the specific example you asked about, the brackets clearly form a unit, so `[ˆ[A − Z]]{3}` requires three matches to `[ˆ[A − Z]]`. Again assuming a common syntax, `[ˆ[A − Z]]` means one character that does not match `[A-Z]`, so a character that is not `A` through `Z`. Since your alphabet consists only of `A` through `Z` and `0` through `9`, `[^[A-Z]]` matches `0` through `9`.

Thus `[^[A-Z]]{3}` matches a three-digit numeral and nothing else.

Comment: As i said also to the other user, thank you! Both helped in my understanding of this kind of problems

Answer (score 0):

First, there's a bunch of problems with your regex.

I believe your "smart" editor has mangled the regex. It's replaced ^ (U+0005E CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT) and - (U+0002D - HYPHEN-MINUS) with the fancy versions: ^ (U+002C6 - MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT) and (U+02212 - MINUS SIGN). They look the same, but they are different characters and have different meanings in a regex. To avoid this, be sure to use a good code editor such as [Atom](https://atom.io/).

Spaces are also important. `[A - Z]` means something different than `[A-Z]`. So are newlines, they are treated literally.

`∗01∗` does not mean to match `01` surrounded by anything. Regexes don't work like file globs. While * does mean "zero or more" like a file glob, it is "zero or more of the immediately preceding thing". `.` matches (almost) anything. So it would be `.*01.*`.

`[ˆ[A − Z]]{3}` should be `[^A-Z]{3}`. `[^...]` means to match what *is not* in the set. `[^A-Z]{3}` means to match exactly 3 of anything which are *not* between A and Z. `123` or `abc` or `!@#`.

Putting it all together: [`[A-Z].*01.*[^A-Z]{3}`](https://regex101.com/r/k4Tmyg/1) says to match exactly *one* character in the set between A and Z, then match anything, then exactly `01`, then anything, then exactly 3 characters which are not in the set between A and Z. `C01;;;` and `blah blah Z blah 01 blah blah abc` both match.

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) is a valuable resource for understanding regexes. [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a very good tutorial site.

> First question is: {3} means that there must be atleast 3 characters that belong to a "part" of the regular expression(lets say 3[A − Z]) or it is strictly refering to the last one ([ˆ[A − Z]])?

`{3}` is a ["quantifier"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). So are `+` (one or more), `*` (zero or more), and `?` (zero or one). All quantifiers match the thing immediately preceding it. `A{3}` means "AAA". `[A-Z]{3}` means exactly three characters in the set of A through Z.

> My second doubt is: if it is the last one, checking if there are atleast 3 occurrences might be easy(just 3 states that check if the char is a number, otherwise exit),right? Otherwise, if it might be any of the possible part of the regular expression, how do i check without a counter(eventually confirm if i shouldnt be using a counter) how many occurrences repeat in any possible state?

Regular expressions are insanely complicated. They are a language unto themselves. Unless this is for a class, use a regular expression library such as [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/).

Comment: thank you! it really helped and i tried to write a simple state machine and it seems to work now.

Comment: @GiacomoMasciarelli A state machine is a good choice. Regexes are often written as a [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) (generally faster) or [NFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) (generally more flexible).